# mod_rewrite not passing querystring

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, php

I have an apache2 server installed with PHP CGI to run php scripts
inside one of my directories I have `.htaccess` file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article\/(\d+)\/?$ article.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

when entering URI such as `http://www.mysite.com/article/132/` the rewrite makes the redirect but inside `article.php` I can't read `$_GET["id"]` (`var_dump` from `$_GET`/`$_REQUEST` results in empty array

in another server I have which has apache with mod_php - everything works fine.

I'm not 100% sure that the CGI is the reason for that - but I have a good reason for assuming so

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds vaguely like mod_negotiation messing things up when you don't want it to. Try adding this to your htaccess file:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

The `Multiviews` options turns on something in mod_negotiation which tries to guess what resource a request is after. When it sees the URI `/article/something` and then it sees that there is a file `/article.php`, it assumes that you meant `/article.php/something` and serves that up outright, completely bypassing mod_rewrite.

Comment: It worked! thanks
can you please explain what does it do?
(I really had  `Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews` in my `.conf`)

Comment: @YaronU. See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews It pretty much does what I described in the answer.