# htaccess will not work with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry for the bad English, English isn't my mother tongue so I'm trying to make the best of it.

I'm having trouble with mod_rewrite when I try to make my URL seo friendlier.
I won't to make my URL from this:

```
http://domain.eu/blog?page=2
```

To this:

```
http://domain.eu/blog/2/
```

My current code:

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# WWW to not WWW.
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rasolutions\.eu$
#RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/rasolutions\.eu\/" [R=301]

# No PERL access/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

# Blog SEO Urls.
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]*)/?$        blog.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blogitem/([0-9]*)/?$    blogitem.php?id=$1    [NC,L]


# Home redirect.
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - make sure you've turned `mod_rewrite` on in the .htaccess file by stating

```
RewriteEngine on
```

If that was already set make sure you have `Multiviews` option disabled by setting

```
Options -Multiviews
```

on the server's configuration file

A similar question:
[mod_rewrite not passing querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715478/mod-rewrite-not-passing-querystring)

### EDIT

Now that I see your full .htaccess - the order of rules there is wrong

you should first check:

```
# Blog SEO Urls.
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]*)/?$ blog.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blogitem/([0-9]*)/?$ blogitem.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

and only after that

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The full file should look like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# Home redirect.
DirectoryIndex home.php

Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
# No PERL access/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

# WWW to not WWW.
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rasolutions\.eu$
#RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/rasolutions\.eu\/" [R=301]

# Blog SEO Urls.
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]*)/?$        blog.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blogitem/([0-9]*)/?$    blogitem.php?id=$1    [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i've updated the start post with my entire htaccess file. If I disable mutliviews it will give me a 404 error page.

Comment: If I could only give you thousand more points... Thank you very much, I've already looked a hour thinking it had to due with those two lines. Thank you very much.